# How to inject interface reference into Spring Controller while junit testing using PowerMockito Testing Framework?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I have Spring Controller, in which one interface is autowired as shown in following class.

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController
{
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeManager employeeManager;

    public int saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        int empId = employeeManager.saveEmployee(employee);
        return empId;
    }
}
```

Now, I created one Junit test class as following.

```
public class EmployeeControllerTest {

    private EmployeeController employeeController ; 
    private EmployeeManager employeeManager ;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        employeeController = PowerMockito.spy(new EmployeeController());
        employeeManager = PowerMockito.mock(EmployeeManager.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetCountOfEmployees()
    { 
        Employee emp = new Employee("Peter");
        int empId = employeeController.saveEmployee(emp);   
        Assert.assertEquals(1, empId);
    }
```

Now after executing test class, I am getting nullPointerException at line `int empId = employeeManager.saveEmployee(employee);` inside `saveEmployee` method of controller.

**I have also tried @Mock annotation, @Spy annotation but not able to execute test case.
So please help to inject `employeeManager` instance in controller while executing test case using PowerMockito.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must used Whitebox.setInternalState to inject your mock into EmployeeController.

Example :

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(EmployeeController, "employeeManager", employeeManager) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if this is correct, but I do have an idea. You are mocking the EmployeeManager class, autowiring it into the controller, and calling a method on it which is throwing a NullPointerException. It is doing this because the employeeManager object inside EmployeeController is the mocked object, and if you call a method on a mock object, then it will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` stems from `employeeManager` being `null`. A mock is created, but never injected/autowired into the controller class. The test doesn't make use of any of Spring's capabilities.